# Error :: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. on real android device testing

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, authentication

[image]

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4[image] |

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /Users/mb/Js/chheilav121/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /Users/mb/Js/chheilav121/android/app/src/google-services.json
  /Users/mb/Js/chheilav121/android/app/src/Debug/google-services.json
  /Users/mb/Js/chheilav121/android/app/google-services.json
```

Answer (score 2):

google-services.json file must be under app folder...

[image]

Comment: thanks buddy ,,,i forget to add it in android app folder ..